# Angular, Typescript and Angular UI with "controller as"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-resource

The combo in the topic is giving me a hard time, I'm sure it's a simple mistake somewhere.

Controller:

```
  class JobCtrl {

      job: Object;  

      public $inject = ['$log', '$resource', 'ApiDataEndpoint', '$stateParams'];  
      constructor(public $log, public $resource, public ApiDataEndpoint, public $stateParams ) {      
           var JobRes = $resource(ApiDataEndpoint.url+'job/:id', {});

           var jobCall = JobRes.get({ id: $stateParams.id},function(){
               this.job = jobCall;
           })
      }  
  }
```

The route is defined like this:

```
.state('app.job', {
        url: '/jobs/:id',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/job.html',
                controller: 'JobCtrl',
                controllerAs: 'vm'
            }
        }
    })
```

in my view I got this:

```
<p>
 Name: {{vm.job.Name}}
</p>
```

But the view never updates when the callback returns. I'm guessing it's either an async problem or a scope problem. Fetching the resource works perfect, the view just never updates. It's seems as I can't set this job from within the callback. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you see `{{vm.job.Name}}` in the view? If so, your code isn't valid and there should be an error. Or do you just see `Name:`?

Comment: I just see Name: I think the JS is valid I'm just not able to set this.job from the callback... If I change my code to use $scope and remove the "as vm" and then in the callback sets $scope.job everything works, but I want to use the "this" syntax

Comment: Doesn't `this.job = jobCall;` assign a $promise?

Comment: @sebastianForsberg $resource is strange about promises...

Comment: `this.job = jobCall;` looks wrong to me. I think this `this` refers to the inner scope of your callback.

Comment: When dealing with resources it should work fine to assign stuff directly, not using the callback: `this.job = JobRes.get({id: $stateParams.id});` should be enough

Comment: @Gustav your solution works like a charm.  now my problem is that I don't understand the code. how does this.job get set to the result from the async call?

Comment: @iCediCe it is some $resource magic! but basically, it keeps the reference and updates the object when the async call is finnished. You can read about it in the documentation

Comment: @Gustav Thanks a lot, I will brush up on the documentation. Comming fom a c# world all this nesting and async calls is a strange cheese...

Comment: @iCediCe I prefer using $http wrapped into a service for the async. If you prefer the $resource style, you should have a look at RestAngular

Comment: @DeblatonJean-Philippe Thank you, I heard about restangular, I will check it out if the scope of the project allows it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this (untested):

```
var jobCall = JobRes.get({ id: $stateParams.id},function(response){
    job = response.data;
})
```

Comment: That was my first guess, but are you sure this shouldn't be out of the constructor scope?

Comment: and simply do `job = response.data;`

Answer (score 0):

this isn't available inside the callback function the way you have it implemented. Change to use lambda and it will be:

From this:

```
var jobCall = JobRes.get({ id: $stateParams.id},function(){
           this.job = jobCall;
       })
```

To this:

```
var jobCall = JobRes.get({ id: $stateParams.id}, (response) => {
           this.job = response.data;
       });
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. The issue is not to access the response but to asign it to 'this'. The solution from @Gustav in the comments to the original question works....